# Table ids missing in Redshift SVV_TABLE_INFO that should be there, looking at STL_QUERY and STL_SCAN

Tags: sql, metadata, amazon-redshift

I am investigating **Redshift** queries and the tables they scan.
I do this by starting with the STL_QUERY system view, then joining the STL_SCAN view to add the tables that are scanned by the query.

Now, when I investigate the query statement, I can see that ONE real Redshift table should be scanned, looking at the SELECT statement. However, the STL_SCAN data shows me three tables (348, 671 and 751341)

Of those 3, only one (751341) is a real one that is found by joining with SVV_TABLE_INFO.

**What are the other 2 tables?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift assigns low numbered table IDs to interim results (projections between query steps, sorting outputs, etc). In some cases interim results are written to disk and scans over these results have an entry in `stl_scan`.

The doc "Query Analysis Workflow" provides comprehensive guidance for reviewing Redshift queries. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-query-analysis-process.html

As a first step, you can start by reviewing the explain plan and the query summary using the following queries:

```
--Explain Plan of a Given Query ID
SELECT userid, query, plannode, info
FROM stl_explain
WHERE query IN (79639676)
ORDER BY query, nodeid, parentid
;

--Processing Summary of a Given Query ID
SELECT *
FROM svl_query_summary a
WHERE query IN  (2251580)
ORDER BY query, stm, seg, step
;
```